# Biblatex: extended version of a paper on arXiv

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am quite often confronted with papers (conference proceedings) that are very cut down due to length limiations. Often authors then would publish an extended version of their paper on arXiv. I would like to print this in my bibliography e.g. as *Author, "Title", Journal etc., extended version: arxiv-id*. Now I do not know you to realise this relation properly with biblatex. I see two approaches:

Keep `published` and `extended` as two different entries in my bibliography and link them:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
    @article{published,
        title={Title}, author={Author}, journal={Journal}, year={2021},
        related={extended}, relatedstring={extended version}
    }
    @online{extended,
        title={Title}, author={Author}, year={2021}, 
        eprint={12345}, eprinttype={arxiv}}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is ugly because it prints the title and year twice. Maybe it is good because the published and the extended version are two separate documents. But then I do not know how to print the entry nicely.

The alternative I see abuses the `eprintclass`-field:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblioa.bib}
    @article{published,
        title={Title}, author={Author}, journal={Journal}, year={2021},
        eprint={12345}, eprinttype={arxiv}, eprintclass={extended version}}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{biblioa.bib}
\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Of course this prints ugly, but maybe that can be fixed (how? I am too unexperienced with writing styles I guess). More severely, I think it is a bad idea to use the `eprintclass`-field for something else than it is intended for.

What would be a suitable approach?

Comment: For things that are difficult to express with existing fields usually the `note` field is convenient (`note={extended version: arxiv-id}`). Of course this does not allow for structured processing by a style but it seems sufficient for your purposes - and reasonably semantically correct as well.

Comment: @Marijn: which leaves me with finding out how biblatex formats the arxiv-id and makes a hyperlink out of it. Do you know the names of the relevant macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the `related` approach. If you are not happy with the default output, you can define your own `relatedtype` and customise its output.

In the following we define `arxivversion`, which prints the arXiv link and title and date if they differ from the published version.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro*{related:arxivversion}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \iffieldsequal{title}{savedtitle}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{title}}%
    \newunit
    \ifdatesequal{}{saved}
      {}
      {\printdate}%
    \newunit
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{published,
  title         = {Title},
  author        = {Author},
  journal       = {Journal},
  year          = {2021},
  related       = {extended},
  relatedtype   = {arxivversion},
  relatedstring = {\autocap{e}xtended version},
}
@online{extended,
  title      = {Title},
  author     = {Author},
  year       = {2021}, 
  eprint     = {12345},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
  \nocite{published}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Author. “Title”. In: Journal (2021). Extended version arXiv: 12345.]

Comment: That looks good! I would never have been able to implement the logic behind the omission of identical title and date.